# allowing single quotes in tsql sqlserver

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql, sql-server-2012

How to use single quotes in sql.

I don't want to use '' (double single quotes) as it will show double single quotes when data is displayed like

```
St. John''s
```

I want when data displays it should be

```
St. John's
```

And I know I can use replace but is there any alternative?

I also have tried QUOTENAME but it's not working

I have column named LOCATIONCITY and I want to insert St. John's and display St. John's But I don't want to insert double single quotes like

```
St. John''s
```

Comment: Where do you want to show it?

Comment: `select 'St. John''s'` displays a single quote character in the result. So I'm not sure what you're talking about when you say that it would display with double quotes. And if this is some question that actually involves working with SQL from another language, then the answer (as always) is to use parameters.

Answer (score 4):

If you do this:

```
create table quote_test(quote_field varchar(50))

insert into quote_test (quote_field) values ('St. John''s')
```

The insert statement with the extra single quote acts as an escape character and it inserts a single quote in the specified column. Running the following commands:

```
select * from quote_test
select * from quote_test where quote_field = 'St. John''s'
```

Would return the following, with a single quote:

```
St. John's
```

If you try to insert with a single quote, the insert string would be broken and it would be invalid syntax.

### [Demo SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/7e76f/1)

Comment: When I run command like this:select * from quote_test where quote_field = 'St. John''s'    It returns St. John''s It is not returning St. John's   I have checked

Comment: @xyz I'm not sure how you're testing it, but if you look at the exact posted syntax in the demo fiddle I posted, you will see it works as stated. Feel free to create a SQL fiddle showing your issue if you can.

Answer (score 0):

You can declare a variable for your value and pass it as a parameter if you want to use in where clause.

In the result set the matching values will not be shown in double single quotes for single quotes.